# How to do O(n) time for this function?

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, time-complexity

I have a array. This array contains values of a stock.

For example;

0. Index -> First Day
1. Index -> 1. Day
2. Index -> 2. Day
   .
   .
   .
   n. Index -> n. Day

And This function should be calculate highest profit. Don't forget, It can be bought first and then sold. The day of purchase must be before the day of sale.

I am trying find to best solution for this function. Can it be O(n) time. Now, this function's time complexity is O(n^2).

```
    public static int getResult(int[] array) {
    int result = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < array.length; j++) {
            int diff = array[j] - array[i];
            if (diff > result) {
                result = diff;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: What's the specification for the code? [Find the largest difference between 2 elements](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-difference-between-two-elements-in-an-array/)? Please edit the post to state it.

Comment: Here's a O(n) approach I've confirmed has the same result as your code.  Create a second array (`minThruArr`) the same size as the first, iterate over your array, and put the minimum value seen thus far into your new array.  This array is the min value up to that element.  Then, iterate through your initial array backwards, keeping track of the maximum value seen thus far (`maxThru`).  For each such index, subtract the min through that index from the max through that index (`maxThru - minThru[i]`).  Keep track of the maximum such value, and that is your result.

Comment: `public static int getResult(int[] array) { int[] minThruArr = new int[array.length]; int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE; for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { min = Math.min(min, array[i]); minThruArr[i] = min; } int result = Integer.MIN_VALUE; int maxThru = Integer.MIN_VALUE; for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { maxThru = Math.max(maxThru, array[i]); result = Math.max(result, maxThru - minThruArr[i]); } return result; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>This can be done in O(n) time. Iterate through the array looking for the largest and smallest number.  At the end return the difference between them.</del>

---

As you iterate, if the number is lower than the last low number, you remember the number and it's highest difference in some kind of stack or node data structure. At the end you return the highest number.

Comment: Hi Alex, I couldn't express it clearly enough. I am sorry about this. I have been edited the question.

Comment: Seems like my pseudo code is still right.  You want to find the biggest possible price difference, right?

Comment: Doesn't your pseudocode only work when the smallest number is before the largest number, since you can't buy it after you've sold it?

Comment: It finds the biggest difference regardless of order, so it doesn't work for what you want, but it does what your original code does.

Comment: The inner loop of the original code starts with `j = i`, so it does take order into account — the second element is always one which comes after the first.

Comment: you might be able to do it with dp

Answer (score 0):

Here's a O(n) approach which has the same result as your code.  Create a second array (`minThruArr`) the same size as the first, iterate over your array, and put the minimum value seen thus far into your new array. This array is the min value up to that element. Then, iterate through your initial array backwards, keeping track of the maximum value seen thus far (`maxThru`). For each such index, subtract the min through that index from the max through that index (`maxThru - minThru[i]`). Keep track of the maximum such value, and that is your result.

```java
public static int getResult(int[] array) {
    int[] minThruArr = new int[array.length];
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        min = Math.min(min, array[i]);
        minThruArr[i] = min;
    }
    int result = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int maxThru = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        maxThru = Math.max(maxThru, array[i]);
        result = Math.max(result, maxThru - minThruArr[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```